# identity server - get updated claims with refresh token

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I put some claims in the access token that comes from DB while login (e.g. `entity_id` and `role`). Now at some stage the `entity_id` claim gets changed and I need to get a new access token with the updated claims. I am doing this using the refresh token to get a new access token but it comes with the same old claims inside; may be because the class implementing `IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator` is not being called in case of refresh token. So how can I get the updated claims in access token? Because user has to logout and re-login otherwise to get the `entity_id` and `role` claims updated.

I know the other option is to make use of the `/userinfo` endpoint for claims but my question here is in this case how the `[Authorize(Roles = "Manager")]` attribute of ASP.NET Core will work and get to know about roles if they don't exist in the access token?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Or put differently - data that changes often is not a good candidate for claims in tokens.

That said - you can make identityserver run through the profile service pipeline again when getting a refreshed token - see here:

https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/reference/client.html?highlight=UpdateAccessTokenClaimsOnRefresh

Comment: OK I did the same, I made IdentityServer run through the profile service pipeline but now the issue is that the method GetProfileDataAsync of ProfileService is being called at the time of getting access token at /token endpoint along with ValidateAsync method of ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator class that makes double DB roundtrip. How can I make this to call only ValidateAsync while requesting access token and only GetProfileDataAsync in case of refresh token?

Comment: GetProfileData was always called for the initial request. Now it is additionally called for the refresh request as well. That's the price you pay.

Comment: OK got it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: this answer has a broken link

Comment: updated link: https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/refresh_tokens.html?highlight=UpdateAccessTokenClaimsOnRefresh